# KAFKA compared to modern In Memory Memory Data Grid (IMDG)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, hazelcast, ignite, infinispan

I have some IMDG experience I am rather new to KAFKA. I am trying to understand the use case for Kafka. I understand it is a streaming/messaging platform. A lot of its issues have some contra parts in the modern In Memory Data Grids. Can you shed a bit light over the use cases when someone would prefer to use Kafka and when you would prefer to use IMDG. I need to draw a parallel.

I will give you one example. I have noticed usage of Kafka for data replication. Although possible I feel that IMDG are more capable and automated for this purpose.

Also I am interested in how these two technologies compliment each other as I don't think they are in direct competition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two types of systems do have some feature overlap, but they still are two different types of systems with dissimilar primary objectives. In that we can't compare them on the primary feature of either.

Kafka is primarily a pub/sub **durable** message broker. Data grids are primarily **in-memory cache systems**. This is the first distinction or key attribute on which one would choose to use either.

On a secondary level, which I believe is where the lines become blurred, both types of system provide some kind of distributed computing capabilities (Kafka Streams, Ignite or Hazelcast compute grid/service) with data ingestion functionality. This, however, cannot be taken as the primary selection criterion.

The two types don't really directly compete with one another **on their respective primary purpose**. A stream-based compute engine may use a data grid for computation or for transient state caching, but I don't see how it would rely on compute/data grids for a reliable, standalone message broker as it would depend on something like Kafka for it.

A small application may dispense with one type to use the secondary features of the other, but an application with high demand for both may in fact need to use both types of systems.

As an example, if you're building a high-volume data pipeline with multiple data sources and you have to use a durable message broker, you will probably have to use Kafka, but if you equally have strong requirements for low-latence querying downsream, you will as well need to use a compute grid, be it for caching or for distributed computing.

Comment: I think the second point where they do overlap a bit with regards of the distributed computing part is the place which creates a bit confusion. The primary aspect I think is clear. Can you say a bit more about the secondary aspect where they do compete a bit ?

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov True. They each offer a flavor of distributed computing, with data locality awareness for the best part. The models are a little different, though (I may be wrong here, but I think Kafka's distributed computing is fine stream-based, but may have sliding window functions or state, but I've used near-batch computing on ignite and hazelcast, executing functions on collections of records). The other thing is the API. I haven't used Kafka streams much, but I know that Hazelcast and Ignite try hard to implement standard interfaces (Collection, Map, etc.), which can be very handy...

Comment: @ernest-kiwele Remember also Hazelcast is two things. [Hazelcast IMDG](https://hazelcast.org/) is the In-Memory Data Grid. [Hazelcast JET](https://jet.hazelcast.org/) is the new streaming engine -- it support streams, sliding windows, etc

Comment: Interesting. This is exactly why I'd hope more answers get posted. How these platforms evolve is just dizzying and I'm sure patterns of usage differ widely from application to application. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I think this question should attract more answers. A bit dissappointed it has not done that yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've been pondering upon the same question recently.  I've came to these conclusions:

Use an IMDG like Ignite/Hazelcast if:

- Your processing use cases makes sense in a compute grid AND your grid, which could have a number of applications/processes in it, is the only consumer for the durable, distributed data streams

Use Kafka if:

- You have a heterogeneous environment of processing layers and you need an independent data integration layer to provide durable, distributed data streams

Also, they are not necessarily mutually exclusive.  You may find that the latter makes sense in your organization.  However some consumers may have specific use cases for an IMDG/IMCG and prefer to tap into the enterprise wide Kafka plane for seed data and re-use its IMDG/IMCG internal data structures for intermediate data streams that is used exclusively within the grid, so no real reason to re-divert those out to Kafka.  It may re-divert results back to Kafka for further dissemination to the rest of the enterprise.

Btw, IMDGs/IMCGs like ignite and hazelcast can provide pub/sub, be as durable as Kafka in terms of data resilience and provide stream processing over it.